# state not updating inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-hooks

```
 const [bolidata, setbolidata] = useState('');
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location?.state) {
     
      setbolidata(location?.state?.data);
      console.log('This is' ,bolidata ) 
      console.log('boli data is manual donation ', location?.state?.data);
    }
  }, []);
  
  console.log("outside", bolidata);
  
  const tabs = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        label: ' Manual Cash Donation',
        component: (
          <CashDonation
            setshowalert={setshowalert}
            handleClose={handleClose}
            themeColor={donationColorTheme.cash}
            handleOpen4={handleOpen4}
            setopendashboard={setopendashboard}
            donationTypes={donationTypes}
            bolidatasss={bolidata}
          />
        ),
      }
```

In this code the `setbolidata` is not updating the state of `bolidata` inside `useEffect` but outside `useEffect` the `boliData` is providing the required details. In both `console.log` the `bolidata` is not providing the data but the log with `location?.state?.data` is providing the data. Note:This is not the full code and `setbolidata` and bolidata is not interfering anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`setbolidata` isn’t supposed to change the value of `bolidata` (and couldn’t even if it was: It is a `const`!).

`setbolidata` changes the value **in the state**.

Next time the component renders, `useState` will pull that new value from the state and assign it to `bolidata`.

The effect callback is, however, running **now** and not *next time the component renders*.

Comment: how can I fix my code then ?..I tried many ways and couldn't find the solutions

Comment: You see how you are making two calls to `console.log` inside the effect callback? And one uses `bolidata` and doesn’t give you the value you want, and the other uses something different and does give you the value you want: Like that.